# Why is my Jenkins throwing 'no such method found' exceptions after restart?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins was restarted. I lost all the projects that had used 'jenkins pipeline'. I see the directories on the server itself, but from the looks of it, Jenkins fails to load them; I don't see the projects on the UI.

Below is the error I see repeating itself. What could be the reason? I am on Jenkins 2.7.4.

```
May 07, 2018 2:32:00 PM com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderCron doRun
WARNING: Cron thread throw an exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jenkins.model.Jenkins.allItems(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderCron.checkTriggers(FolderCron.java:117)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderCron.doRun(FolderCron.java:101)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jenkins.model.Jenkins.allItems(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderCron.checkTriggers(FolderCron.java:117)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderCron.doRun(FolderCron.java:101)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It is not classnotfound it is nosuchmethod!!

Comment: thank you :) been googling for some answer similar to my issue for a while already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only clue for now is in [JENKINS 48649](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48649):

> Facing the same error after upgrading one of the plugins.

So if you have recently upgraded some plugins, try and:

- empty your `JENKINS_HOME/plugins` folder
- relaunch and re-install only the [JENKINS Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin)
- see if the issue persists
- add your other plugins incrementally

The [OP iCodeLikeImDrunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802281/icodelikeimdrunk) actually [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220468/why-is-my-jenkins-throwing-no-such-method-found-exceptions-after-restart/50220565#comment87537033_50220565):

> we just upgrade to the latest, seems to resolve everything.

Comment: will try that. i didnt change anything, just restarted jenkins because one of the jobs was hanging... then poof, every pipeline related project disappears...

Comment: @iCodeLikeImDrunk Before that, if possible, try simply to reboot the Jenkins server, to see if there was not an issue with one process.

Comment: in the end, we just upgrade to the latest, seems to resolve everything...

Comment: @iCodeLikeImDrunk Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.